# Small and large extra dimension(s) of the physical space

Tags: spacetime, dimensional-analysis, topology, spacetime-dimensions, compactification

Trying to make sense of small and large extra dimension(s) of phyiscal space in a simple intuitive example.

Consider a two dimensional manifold like $\mathbb{R}^2$ and we are trying to add a small and a large extra dimension.

Do we mean by small extra dimension in this case something like $(0,1) \times \mathbb{R}$ (the flat case) or $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$ (the curved case)?

Do we mean by large extra dimension something like $\mathbb{R^2} \times \mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}^3$?

Do we mean in the case of our three dimensional space that basically we have a **base space** of our phyiscal three dimensional space with a **total space** built by adding a fiber and thus creating **a fiber bundle** or a even more general an arbitrary **total spac**e?

Does the extra dimension need to be real or **can we even consider the complex manifolds**, in the case of adding extra dimension to the phyiscal space, for example $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{R^3}$ or (Riemann surface) $\times \mathbb{R^3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The word *large* and *small* are determined by a [metric tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor)/[characteristic length scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_length). [Small dimensions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/529376/2451) can typically not be detected by current experiments. Large dimensions are typically of cosmological size, however, see e.g. the [ADD model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_extra_dimensions).
2. The topology of  extra dimensions need not be compact: E.g. the metric tensor could in principle contain a [warp factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randall%E2%80%93Sundrum_model) that makes the extra dimension effectively small.
3. The full spacetime is not necessarily a total space of a [fiber bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_bundle).
4. Extra dimensions may have a [complex structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_manifold), such as e.g. a [Calabi-Yau manifold](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4972/2451).